Issue with Mismatched Tweaked Public Keys in Ed25519 Using Libsodium in C++
I'm working on a cryptographic project using the Ed25519 curve and Libsodium in C++. My goal is to tweak an initial key pair by adding a derived scalar to the initial seed and then generate the corresponding tweaked key pair. However, I am encountering a problem where the tweaked public key derived from the tweaked private key does not match the tweaked public key calculated directly using scalar multiplication and point addition.
Problem in Detail:
I generate an initial key pair using a random seed. I then derive a scalar from a static value and add this scalar to the initial seed to get the tweaked seed. I use this tweaked seed to generate a new key pair.
Additionally, I attempt to calculate the tweaked public key directly by performing scalar multiplication of the derived scalar with the base point and then adding the result to the initial public key. The issue arises when the tweaked public key derived from the private key does not match the directly calculated tweaked public key.
 #include <sodium.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <cstring>  // For strlen

    // Helper functions to print and handle keys
    void print_hex(const std::string &label, const unsigned char *data, size_t length) {
    std::cout << label << ": ";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (int)data[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::dec << std::endl;
}

std::vector<unsigned char> derive_scalar(const unsigned char *static_value) {
    unsigned char hash[crypto_hash_sha512_BYTES];
    crypto_hash_sha512(hash, static_value, strlen((char *)static_value));
    return std::vector<unsigned char>(hash, hash + 32);  // Use the first 32 bytes
}

void clamp_scalar(unsigned char *scalar) {
    scalar[0] &= 248;
    scalar[31] &= 127;
    scalar[31] |= 64;
    }

int main() {
    // Initialize sodium library
    if (sodium_init() == -1) {
        return 1; // Initialization failed
    }

    // Generate initial key pair
    unsigned char initial_seed[crypto_sign_SEEDBYTES];
    randombytes_buf(initial_seed, sizeof initial_seed);

    unsigned char initial_public_key[crypto_sign_PUBLICKEYBYTES];
    unsigned char initial_private_key[crypto_sign_SECRETKEYBYTES];
    crypto_sign_seed_keypair(initial_public_key, initial_private_key, initial_seed);

    print_hex("Initial Seed", initial_seed, sizeof initial_seed);
    print_hex("Initial Public Key", initial_public_key, sizeof initial_public_key);
    print_hex("Initial Private Key", initial_private_key, sizeof initial_private_key);

    // Derive scalar
    const unsigned char static_value[] = "static value for hash";
    auto derived_scalar = derive_scalar(static_value);

    print_hex("Derived Scalar", derived_scalar.data(), derived_scalar.size());

    // Perform scalar addition for seed
    unsigned char tweaked_seed[crypto_sign_SEEDBYTES];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < crypto_sign_SEEDBYTES; ++i) {
        tweaked_seed[i] = initial_seed[i] + derived_scalar[i];
    }

    clamp_scalar(tweaked_seed);

    print_hex("Tweaked Seed", tweaked_seed, sizeof tweaked_seed);

    // Generate tweaked key pair
    unsigned char tweaked_public_key[crypto_sign_PUBLICKEYBYTES];
    unsigned char tweaked_private_key[crypto_sign_SECRETKEYBYTES];
    crypto_sign_seed_keypair(tweaked_public_key, tweaked_private_key, tweaked_seed);

    print_hex("Tweaked Public Key (From Private)", tweaked_public_key, sizeof tweaked_public_key);
    print_hex("Tweaked Private Key", tweaked_private_key, sizeof tweaked_private_key);

    // Calculate tweaked public key directly
    unsigned char scalar_mult_result[crypto_scalarmult_BYTES];
    crypto_scalarmult_base(scalar_mult_result, derived_scalar.data());

    unsigned char tweaked_public_key_direct[crypto_core_ed25519_BYTES];
    crypto_core_ed25519_add(tweaked_public_key_direct, initial_public_key, scalar_mult_result);

    print_hex("Tweaked Public Key (Direct)", tweaked_public_key_direct, sizeof tweaked_public_key_direct);

    // Verify if the direct calculation matches the tweaked public key from the private key
    if (memcmp(tweaked_public_key, tweaked_public_key_direct, crypto_core_ed25519_BYTES) == 0) {
        std::cout << "Tweaked Keys Match: True" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Tweaked Keys Match: False" << std::endl;
    }

    // Test scalar multiplication and point addition consistency
    std::cout << "\n=== Using scalar multiplication===\n";
    unsigned char G[crypto_core_ed25519_BYTES];
    unsigned char G2[crypto_core_ed25519_BYTES];
    unsigned char G3[crypto_core_ed25519_BYTES];
    unsigned char G5[crypto_core_ed25519_BYTES];

    unsigned char n[32];

    // G
    memset(n, 0, 32);
    n[0] = 1;
    crypto_scalarmult_ed25519_base_noclamp(G, n);
    print_hex("G", G, sizeof G);

    // 2G
    memset(n, 0, 32);
    n[0] = 2;
    crypto_scalarmult_ed25519_base_noclamp(G2, n);
    print_hex("2G", G2, sizeof G2);

    // 3G
    memset(n, 0, 32);
    n[0] = 3;
    crypto_scalarmult_ed25519_base_noclamp(G3, n);
    print_hex("3G", G3, sizeof G3);

    // rG
    int r = 5;
    if (r > 100) r = 100;  // Safeguard
    memset(n, 0, 32);
    n[0] = r;
    crypto_scalarmult_ed25519_base_noclamp(G5, n);
    print_hex("5G", G5, sizeof G5);

    std::cout << "\n=== Now using point addition===\n";

    unsigned char G_add[crypto_core_ed25519_BYTES];

    // G + G
    crypto_core_ed25519_add(G_add, G, G);
    print_hex("G+G point", G_add, sizeof G_add);

    // G + 2G
    crypto_core_ed25519_add(G_add, G, G2);
    print_hex("G+2G point", G_add, sizeof G_add);

    // G + G multiple times
    unsigned char Gr[crypto_core_ed25519_BYTES];
    memcpy(Gr, G, sizeof G);
    for (int i = 1; i < r; ++i) {
        crypto_core_ed25519_add(Gr, Gr, G);
    }
    print_hex("5G point", Gr, sizeof Gr);

    std::cout << "\n=== Now using point subtraction===\n";

    unsigned char G_sub[crypto_core_ed25519_BYTES];

    // G - G
    crypto_core_ed25519_sub(G_sub, G, G);
    print_hex("G-G point", G_sub, sizeof G_sub);

    // 2G - G
    crypto_core_ed25519_sub(G_sub, G2, G);
    print_hex("2G-G point", G_sub, sizeof G_sub);

    // 3G - G
    crypto_core_ed25519_sub(G_sub, G3, G);
    print_hex("3G-G point", G_sub, sizeof G_sub);

    // rG - G
    crypto_core_ed25519_sub(G_sub, G5, G);
    print_hex("5G-G point", G_sub, sizeof G_sub);

    return 0;
    }`

Expected Outcome:
I expect the tweaked public key derived from the private key to match the tweaked public key calculated directly using scalar multiplication and point addition.
The tweaked public key derived from the private key does not match the directly calculated tweaked public key.
